# Is there a way to force indexing to require an enum class for type safety?

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, c++20, type-safety

Let's say I have an array of integers, one for each member of a particular enum class. I can cast the enum class to an int to index the array but I'd rather use the enum class for type safety since that's the only type that should be allowed, in my case, to index that array.

1. Is there a way to do this without overloading the [] operator?
2. If I overload the operator there will be an extra function call cost, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about a raw c-style-array, then there is little chance of forcing the index type to be an enum class. However, your assumption in point 2. is not necessarily true. If you inline define the function along with its declaration chances are high that for a trivial wrapper function the compiler will optimise the call:

```
enum class E {/*...*/};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct A {
  T data[N];
  auto& operator[](E e) {
    return data[static_cast<std::size_t>(e)];
  }
  auto const& operator[](E e) const {
    return data[static_cast<std::size_t>(e)];
  }
};
```

[The calls to these inline functions are removed by the compiler. (live demo)](https://godbolt.org/z/sM7Mh9hKe)

Comment: One of the trade-offs of this is that it is not possible to iterate over elements (unless some other scheme is implemented, such as `begin()` and `end()` iterators).

Comment: @Peter That would be a matter of implementing all the required functions. I don't think you even have implement your own iterators here. Just return `std::begin(data)` / `std::end(data)` respectively. Also, contrary to my answer, one might want to hide the `data` member.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a need to define new iterator types, and I'm aware it is possible to implement `begin()`/`end()`/etc member functions for the class.   Point is that indexing to be (values of) an enum type and iterating over the elements are largely inconsistent design requirements

Comment: Unfortunately for me, the MSVC compiler spits out a lot more asm than the GCC, but I've already answered the question of whether or not the extra type safety is worth it since I've already used it to find errors ><  Thanks a bunch. I also included the enum class as a template parameter to make this structure very generic.